# Wget: How to bypass "hotlinking" protected image

Tags: linux, bash, web, wget, hotlinking

Is it possible to bypass "hotlink" image protection? i'm not trying to post it on other sites just to download.
when i download the following image, using wget:

```
http://comicsbook.ru/upload/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-Trollface-%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83-70813.jpg
```

I'm getting redirected to:

```
http://comicsbook.ru/trollface/70813?na-bortu
```

I have no idea where to start.
What I've tried so far:

```
curl "http://comicsbook.ru" -s -L -b cookie.c -c cookie.c -b "$COOKIEPAR" > index.$TEMP
wget http://comicsbook.ru/upload/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-Trollface-%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83-70813.jpg
```

Comment: Where to start: hotlink protection relies on the [HTTP `Referer` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_REFERER), not on cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `--refer=URL` option of `wget`.
Perhaps you could try:

```
wget --referer=http://comicsbook.ru http://comicsbook.ru/upload/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-Trollface-%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83-70813.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

To download this image, run the following curl command :

```
curl -e 'http://comicsbook.ru/trollface/70813?na-bortu' -A "Mozilla/5.0" -L -b /tmp/c -c /tmp/c -s 'http://comicsbook.ru/upload/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-Trollface-%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83-70813.jpg' > image.jpg
```

All the magic is in `-e` switch : the [referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)

Comment: Yes, there's some not needed options, but you can re-use them for another `web-scraping` use case, it's built to works as close as possible like a real browser.